# Angular7 drop zone: click event not triggered

Tags: angular, typescript, onclick, angular-material, angular7

After reading this [blog post](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-drag-and-drop-with-the-angular-material-cdk-2e0237857290) about angular material 7 new features regarding drag and drop interactions I decided toying with the example'code.

It works around three lists with drag and drop events moving elements between the three lists. This works perfectly, the issue arises when trying modifying the first lists such that its elements become buttons:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of newItems" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag>
<button (click)="clicked($event)"> {{ item }}</button>
</div>
```

The problem is that the click event seems to not get triggered as if the drag-and-drop events had "overwritten them".

Here is the code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-drag-drop-bwkdcy

EDIT: found a workaround with an event listener, no biggie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(mousedown)="clicked($event)"` gets the job done.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the function $event.stopPropagation() to only trigger this event

```
<div *ngFor="let item of newItems" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag>
     <button (click)="$event.stopPropagation();clicked($event)"> {{ item }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, have not tried yours because `mousedown` is good enough here.